# Dont want to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH each time

Tags: linux, git, compilation

The issue started when git was giving following error message 
"fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'"

to resolve this I had to recompile git by first compiling libcurl. while compiling git I had set CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS to include path of libcurl libs and header files. Git got compiled successfully and I was able to remove the above error message.

However, to run the above command I first need to set LD_LIBRARY_FLAG to define the path of custom libcurl folder. Is there a way, I dont have to set this flag every time for every user before executing git command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options.

You can put the libraries in the system library directories, or you can add the location of the libraries to the system directories.

A better option (safer, and doesn't need superuser privileges) is to tell the linker to set an "rpath" in the binaries, which bakes the directory into the executables, so you don't need to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH. You do that by using the `-rpath` linker option or by setting the `LD_RUN_PATH` environment variable while linking.

Another option is to simply avoid linking dynamically to `libcurl.so`, by linking to the static `libcurl.a` archive instead.

Comment: Strangely when I copy the binaries over to a different server its running without me setting ld_library_Path. But on the compiled server i am requried to set it. Both the servers have same configuration.